# Module WebHelper could not be found and loaded

Tags: codeception

I'm just starting to learn codeception and have one trouble in beginning.
When I run `./vendor/bin/codecept build`, I get this exeption:

> Module WebHelper could not be found and loaded

My acceptance.suite.yml looks like this

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser
        - WebHelper
    config:
        PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://test-6.local/'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Helper classes are dynamically generated and there are no standard names.
Try \Helper\Acceptance (default name of acceptance helper in Codeception 2.1)
and AcceptanceHelper (used in 2.0),
if neither works, look at tests/_support directory and copy a complete name of helper class.

Comment: Please create a new question and paste your configuration

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem. See photos.
[image]